# capturing regex value with a ? literal

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So I have this regex:

```
$text = '"sadfsafsafsafsaf"';
$text2 = '"sadfsafsafsafsaf';
$matches = array();

preg_match('/"(.+)"?/', $text, $matches);
```

In this Case I intend to just capture sadfsafsafsafsaf without the quotation mark, hence in both cases in which I use `$text` and `$text2` into `preg_match()` I want the matched output in `$matches[1]` to be just sadfsafsafsafsaf

However when I used `$text`, the value of the match will instead be sadfsafsafsafsaf (ie. there will be another quotation mark in the end)

Is there a way to change my regex so that in both cases it will be sadfsafsafsafsaf?

Note: Before anyone asks why not just use `trim()`...it's because I just want to strip out the first outer quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^"]+` will capture any number of adjacent non-quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `.+` to `.*`, and adding a `$` to the end of your pattern.  The problem you are having is that `.+` matches everything it can, including the trailing quote mark.  The subsequent clause, `"?`, is then ignored because it is optional, by virtue of the question mark.

Using `[^"]+` would also have worked, as this means 'any non-empty string of characters that aren't double quotes'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look for a literal question mark (or any other symbol that is special to the regex engine) you must escape the character: `\?`

Comment: From the examples given, I'm not sure searching for a string with an actual question mark in it was the desired effect here...

Comment: yeah i wasn't sure... he mentioned capturing a literal ? in his actual question, so....

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR`:

```
/"(.*)"|(.*)/
```

Will get the text inside cotes or outside if cotes isn't found.